# Python implementing rod cutting algorithm

Tags: python, debugging

Im practicing for dynamic programming 
and im new to python as well. 
When I try this in the shell.

```
def cut_rod(p, n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    q = float('-inf')
    for i in range(n):
        q = max(q, p[i] + cut_rod(p, n-1-i))
    return q

p = [1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20,24,30]
print(timeit.repeat("cut_rod(p, 4)", "from __main__ import cut_rod",
              number =1000))
```

It warns me that p is not a global variable. in timeit function
Isn't p already a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not importing `p`:

```
print(timeit.repeat("cut_rod(p, 4)", "from __main__ import cut_rod, p",
              number =1000))
```

The `timeit` executes the code inside a controlled environment, hence you must explicitly pass everything required by the statement.